# C++ Combine 2 Tchar

Tags: c++, tchar

I'm trying to combine 2 tchar.

```
char username[UNLEN+1];
DWORD username_len = UNLEN+1;
GetUserName(username, &username_len);
TCHAR* appdatapath ="C:\\Users\\"+username+"\\AppData";
```

But I get error error at appdatapath line. How can I combine 2 tchar? Thanks

Comment: [`std::string` or `std::wstring`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string)? Or make your own `tstring` by using `std::basic_string<TCHAR>`?

Answer (score 5):

Have a look at [strcat](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strcat/) and [wcscat](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cwchar/wcscat/). You can't add char pointer with char array.

If you are on a windows machine, you can use `_tcscat` which will redirect to the right function to use depending on `_UNICODE` and `_MBCS` defines.

Might want to use the safe versions as well by appending _s to the function name.

As pointed in the comments, you can also use snprintf like so:

```
const size_t concatenated_size = 256;
char concatenated[concatenated_size];

snprintf(concatenated, concatenated_size, "C:\\Users\\%s\\AppData", username);
```

Since you have string literals before and after the runtime string, it is probably a better approach.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg You're right and probably better in this particular case. Thanks for the suggestion. Edited the answer to add it.

Answer (score 4):

To answer the question in the title: you concatenate two `TCHAR` strings using the [`_tcscat`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa272954%28v=vs.60%29.aspx) function.

However, there are other issues in your code related to this: [`GetUserName`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724432%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) expects a `LPTSTR`, i.e. a pointer to a buffer `TCHAR` characters. Furthermore, there's another `TCHAR` usage in

```
TCHAR* appdatapath ="C:\\Users\\"+username+"\\AppData";
```

The issue with this is that the type to which `TCHAR` expands changes depending on whether `_UNICODE` is defined. In particular, if you set it, `TCHAR` (eventually) expands to `wchar` and hence `GetUserName` expects a `wchar_t*` but you pass a `char*`. Another issue is that you cannot concatenate C arrays using the `+` operator.

I suggest to stop worrying about `TCHAR` in the first place and always just compile with `_UNICODE` defined - and use `wchar` throughout your code. Also, since you're using C++, just use `std::wstring`:

```
wchar username[UNLEN+1];
DWORD username_len = UNLEN+1;
GetUserNameW(username, &username_len);
std::wstring appdatapath = L"C:\\Users\\";
appdatapath += username;
appdatapath += L"\\AppData";
```

Last but not least: your entire code can probably be replaced with a call to the [`SHGetSpecialFolderPath`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762204%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function - pass `CSIDL_APPDATA` to it to get the "AppData" path.

Answer (score 3):

```
#include <tchar.h>

const size_t stringSize= 20;
TCHAR value[stringSize] = { 0 };

_tcscat_s(value, stringSize, TEXT("appendMe"));
```

MSDN: [_tcscat_s](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/d45bbxx4.aspx)