# copy file to windir c

Tags: c, arrays, string, tchar

I need to copy one file to windir, So I do:

```
TCHAR windir[MAX_PATH];
GetWindowsDirectory(windir, MAX_PATH);
```

to get the windir.

```
char newLocation[]="text.txt"; // how to add the windir here?
BOOL stats=0;
CopyFile(filename, newLocation, stats);
```

My problem is, I want to add the windir value before the text.txt in char newLocation[].

Any ideas?

Comment: For the last 10+ years, UAC has prevented standard users from copying files to the Windows or Program Files directory. It started being discouraged in XP, and was totally prohibited when Vista was released. How could you have missed this news (that's been written about here at least 1000 times previously, with every Windows-related programming language tag in existence AFAIK)?

Comment: yeah, it needs administrator permissions to work... so user can decide if he wants it to work or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try concatenating the strings, like this?

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

char* concat(char *s1, char *s2)
{
    char *result = malloc(strlen(s1)+strlen(s2)+1);//+1 for the zero-terminator
    //in real code you would check for errors in malloc here
    strcpy(result, s1);
    strcat(result, s2);
    return result;
}
```

If that won't work, give [wcscat()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cwchar/wcscat/) a shot!

---

Sources:

1. [How do I concatenate two strings in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8465006/how-to-concatenate-2-strings-in-c)
2. [What is difference between TCHAR and WCHAR?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4205809/what-is-difference-between-tchar-and-wchar)
3. [C++ Combine 2 Tchar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21578455/c-combine-2-tchar)

Comment: exactly! concatenate windir variable before the "text.txt"

Comment: my fault! It gives me an error: [Error] invalid conversion from 'void*' to 'char*' [-fpermissive]

Comment: this line: char *result = malloc(strlen(s1)+strlen(s2)+1);

Comment: Hmm then you should cast the result of `malloc` like this: `char *result = (char*) malloc(strlen(s1)+strlen(s2)+1);` and let me know!